# Can I take user name input in Website link and modify the content according to it ? (using JavaScript HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am Trying to make a Project and what it does is.. Create customized Birthday card according to user's input.

For e.g. - I will put my friends name in Website link Example - https://folder/file/**Jhon**/
So now on Jhon's birthday I will share above customize link and he will see a customize card.
[Basically I somehow want to capture user input from weblink and then in code I can update my HTML to customize the web page.]

Step 1 - It will take **Input from User in the website Link** [Image of where user will enter input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgPcp.png)

Step 2 - So now when user reload the page the page changes to user input.

If anyone can help me in this task of how to get that data entered in link in my HTML that would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: yes, you can do that, that's how the world wide web works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the docs for `Window.location` at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

For your example of https://something.com/file/John, you could do something like:

```js
let name = window.location.toString().split('/').pop()
```

This assign the value of everything after the last `/` in the URL to the variable `name`.